# how to publish VB.NET web app to my Azure Windows 2012 R2 VM

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows, azure, iis

In the build menu > Publish command, which options to I select to simply publish my Visual Basic 2015 VB.NET web app to IIS on my Azure Windows 2012 server R2 VM?

I'm not sure I want to publish to "Microsoft Azure Web Apps".  Seems like that would skip my VM.  On my VM I have other apps running that my web app will need to share files with.

I tried selecting "Custom", but what do I set "Server" , "Site name" , and Destination URL to? 
 Do I use my VM Deployment Name of Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up Webdeploy in the azure VM. it is same as an on-premises server.

[Web Deploy Installation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569059%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).. You need to install prerequisites - .net framework.

[Configuring IIS 7 with webdeploy](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy) / [Or with IIS8](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later)

[Set up endpoints on azure vm to do webdeploy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/). Port 8172 for Webdeploy.

Then you can create a publish profile in Visual Studio 2012/13 to deploy to this endpoint. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or You can do it using Powershell scripts. sample- http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Deploy-a-Web-App-to-Two-99f1a3bc

Comment: Note:  I'm using Visual Studio 2015, not 2012/13.  Any significant differences?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup web deploy on your VM:

1. [Installing and Configuring Web Deploy on IIS 8.0 or Later](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later).
2. Also yopu need to open TCP 8172 in Azure for your VM.

After doing this you can use Visual Studio to publish your app using Web Deploy option in wizard.

Comment: After this, which settings to I select for Build > Publish ?  Do I select "Custom"?

Comment: Yes, Build > Publish and them "Custom".